# Load stash partials with custom extension

Tags: add-on, stash, add-on-development, filesystem

I'm trying to parse markdown files stored on the server, and display them inside EE templates in a nice automatic fashion.

My first idea was to read the files using [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash), then parse them using [Smartdown](https://github.com/experience/smartdown.ee_addon). However, I have run into a problem:

**Stash assumes the files have an extension of `.html`.** If I use this:

```
{exp:stash:get name="index.md" file="yes"}
```

I get the error:

> Stash: the file "/path/to/stash/index.md.html" was not found.

Is there a way to tell Stash not to automatically add the `.html` extension?

Alternatively, is there another easy way to read in files (and cache them)?

Comment: Which version of stash are you using? Looks like the file param will be depreciated FWIW: https://github.com/croxton/Stash/tree/dev#file--yesno I guess I wonder if you'd get the same error with {stash:embed} or not and the most recent beta.

Comment: I'm kind of thinking this will turn into a feature request :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a great idea to me. I've added it to the issue list:

https://github.com/croxton/Stash/issues/31

Answer (score 2):

Stash currently only supports templates with a `.html` extension (mod.stash.php):

```
$file_path = $this->path . implode('/', $file_path) . '.html';
```

[This answer originally included an untested Stash code tweak which I've removed as Mark's confirmed that it won't work.]

Comment: I don't think this will work, Stash runs the filename through the url_title() helper function and that will strip out the period .

The reason it works this way currently is I didn't want to allow the possibility for local file inclusion type attacks, should anyone be foolish enough to use a dynamic/user-submitted value for a file name.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Mark. I only had a cursory look at the code, so it was a bit of a shot in the dark. I've removed the suggested code changes from my post.